# Program skips code or just freezes when process is started in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project that downloads a file and gives output to user. Pretty straightforward...
However, my project doesn't show the form and just does the process first not even changing text progress, or even freezes when not debugged.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace mainUI
{
    public partial class Clean : Form
    {
       
        private Rectangle lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4, lab5, prog1, prog2, bttn1;
        private Size form;
        public string topass { get; set; }

        private void Clean_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label4.Text = "Do not panic if frozen! WinPE is not optimsied for high loads!";
            Downld();

        }
        private void Downld()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"MSWISO\MSWISO.exe",
                Arguments = topass,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
            {
                process.Start();

                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string WhtOut = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    int giveProgress;
                    string newOut = WhtOut.TrimEnd('%');
                   if (int.TryParse(newOut, out giveProgress))
                    {
                        label4.Text = "Current progress: " + WhtOut;
                        progressBar2.Value = giveProgress;
                    }
                   
                }
               process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        public Clean()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Resize += Clean_rsize;
            form = this.Size;
            lab1 = new Rectangle(label1.Location, label1.Size);
            lab2 = new Rectangle(label2.Location, label2.Size);
            lab3 = new Rectangle(label3.Location, label3.Size);
            lab4 = new Rectangle(label4.Location, label4.Size);
            lab5 = new Rectangle(label5.Location, label5.Size);
            prog1 = new Rectangle(progressBar1.Location, progressBar1.Size);
            prog2 = new Rectangle(progressBar2.Location, progressBar2.Size);
            bttn1 = new Rectangle(button1.Location, button1.Size);
        }

        private void Clean_rsize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            resizeControl(lab1, label1);
            resizeControl(lab2, label2);
            resizeControl(lab3, label3);
            resizeControl(lab4, label4);
            resizeControl(lab5, label5);
            resizeControl(prog1, progressBar1);
            resizeControl(prog2, progressBar2);
            resizeControl(bttn1, button1);
        }
        private void resizeControl(Rectangle r, Control c)
        {
            float xRatio = (float)this.Width / form.Width;
            float yRatio = (float)this.Height / form.Height;

            int newX = (int)(r.X * xRatio);
            int newY = (int)(r.Y * yRatio);

            int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
            int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);

            c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
            c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Opacity == 1)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
            Opacity += .4;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Opacity == 0)
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
            Opacity -= .4;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some videos...

With debug:
https://imgur.com/a/3Y7vocX

No debug ( when clicked process doesn't respond, sometimes just freezes too ):
https://imgur.com/a/0A3QU9s

Thanks!

Comment: Don't block the UI thread